# 1064 SQL error in REPLACE syntax on ';' symbol

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update `products` set `content` = replace(`content`, '<img alt="" src="/filecache/e3c55a5bb1b984566c01ae38e83fb04a.jpg" style="border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" border="0">', '')
```

got 1064 error on ";" symbol, when i simulating query. How to make valid request?

Comment: What is the datatype of the field `content`

Comment: @SumeshTG  text.

Comment: Your query as it is written works fine.

Comment: @Nick but i still got this problem, im using phpmyadmin 4.6

Comment: you should be escaping the semicolons

Comment: @LelioFaieta but i need delete this tags wits semicolons)